# I know how to solve these equations, but I'm not sure what t' represents?

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-biology

I am investigating the [**Wilson Cowan neuron population model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%E2%80%93Cowan_model), and I can follow most of it, but I'm not sure what is meant by ***t'*** in the equation for proportion of neurons in the refractory period. The equation of interest is below.

[image]

Comment: As a side note. The mathematical expression you drew is not an equation (there is no equal sign).

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, t' is just a dummy variable used to represent time over the refractory period since the integral is from t-r to t.